# Voice authentication

Tags: audio, voice-recognition, speech

I am stuck in big problem, because I don't have any idea or example how to do it.
What i need to do is compare two voices, eg:

- person 1 said "hello"
- person 2 said "hello"
- after that if person 1 say again "hello" system should be able to identify whether it's person 1 or person 2 (it is like voice authentication system).

I need to do this in C# or C++.

I found that "Microsoft speech API" and "synthetic toolkit" will help full for my task but I didn't found good tutorial or way to do it. Can anyone please help to success this task

Comment: Maybe using neural network?

Answer (score -1):

If you're just looking for a library that will help you with this, check this page out.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_speech_recognition_software

If your actual job is creating speech recognition code from scratch, then you're going to have a much more difficult job. Especially since there are several different routes you can go. Nearly all of them require some kind of feature extraction though (fft for example). So make sure you've prepped up on your signal processing methods. After you've extracted your features you can begin implementing several different methods. Hidden-markov models, neural networks (of many different varieties..), cross correlation...

Hidden markov model paper
http://mi.eng.cam.ac.uk/~mjfg/mjfg_NOW.pdf

Comment: Sorry, speech recognition software has no relation to the original question, this question is about recognizing speaker, not speech. It is pretty different task.